# Suppressing Semicolon Warnings in JSHint with Gulp

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, jshint

I am currently using JSHint with my Gulp workflow, and would like to suppress the semicolon errors when working with JavaScript.

I'm currently using gulp-jshint. How do I enable the "asi" flag within Gulp to make the errors go away?

The type of error I am receiving is:

> ~/bootstrap-4.0.0-alpha/js/src/modal.js: line 1, col 26, Missing semicolon.

Despite it being valid JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated!

Here's my Gulp File in case it helps:

```
    // Load Node Modules/Plugins
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var del = require('del');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint'); 

// Process Styles
gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp.src('scss/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

// Process Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
       return gulp.src('js/src/*.js')
           .pipe(jshint())
           .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(concat('bootstrap.js'))
           .pipe(uglify())
           .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('clean', del.bind(null, ['.tmp', 'dist']));

// Watch tasks
gulp.task('watch', function() {
       gulp.watch('scss/*.scss', 'styles');
       gulp.watch('js/src/*.js', 'scripts');
});

gulp.task('build', ['styles', 'scripts', 'watch']);

gulp.task('default', ['clean'], () => {
  gulp.start('build');
});
```

Comment: semicolon errors? you should use semicolons when writing JS, don't let the interpreter decide

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In `.jshintrc`, set the following to tolerate Automatic Semicolon Insertion:

```
"asi" : true,
```

As described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-jshint), which points you to [this example](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/examples/.jshintrc).